# Change state in multiply SO

Tags: odoo, odoo-8, odoo-9

I made this report that is called from an action in a tree view of SO.
So i can select few reports and print them out.

The thing is that i want to change state in Sale Orders that I selected and printed out the reports. State should change from "draft" to "sent". How can I do this?

```xml
<data>

    <report 
        id="report_het_sale_order"
        string="Het Sale Order Pdf"
        model="sale.order"
        name="het.het_sale_order"
        rml="config_het/report/het_sale_order.ods"
        menu="True"
    />

    <record model="ir.actions.report.xml" id="report_hetl_sale_order">
        <field name="report_type">aeroo</field>
        <field name="parser_loc">config_het/report/het_sale_order.pyc</field>
        <field name="tml_Source">file</field>
        <field name="parser_state">loc</field>
        <field name="out_format" ref="report_aeroo.report_mimetypes_pdf_odt"/>
        <field name="in_format">oo-ods</field>
        <field name="auto" eval="True" />
    </record>
```

Comment: How do you call the print action from your wizard? Have you looked into the "Print" button and the method behind it in the original Odoo code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it by modifying AbstractModel

For example:

```
<report 
            id="agedpartnerbalance_template"
            string="Aged Partner Template"
            model="account.move" 
            report_type="qweb-pdf"
            file="account.report_agedpartnerbalance" 
            name="account.report_agedpartnerbalance"
        />


    class ReportAgedPartnerBalance(models.AbstractModel):

        _name = 'report.account.report_agedpartnerbalance'


        @api.model
        def render_html(self, docids, data=None):
            *****
            Your Logic
            docs = self.env[model].browse(self.env.context.get('active_id'))
            for doc in docs:
                doc.state = 'sent'
            *****
            docargs = {
                'doc_ids': self.ids,
                'doc_model': model,
                'data': data['form'],
                'docs': docs,
                'time': time,
                'get_partner_lines': movelines,
                'get_direction': total,
            }
            return self.env['report'].render('account.report_agedpartnerbalance', docargs)
```